# How can I find out which network an ad is from in AdMob Mediation?

Tags: ios, admob

Is there a way to determine which network a specific ad is from when using AdMob Mediation?  For example, within the interstitialDidReceiveAd:(GADInterstitial *)ad method, does the variable ad have a specific property that contains the name of the ad network that the ad is from?  I want to use the specific ad network to manipulate how my app works in terms of how to properly dismiss the view.

Answer (score 2):

On Android you can do something like this:

```
adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        super.onAdLoaded();
        Log.i("TEST", "onAdLoaded: " + adView.getMediationAdapterClassName());
    }
});
```

Which will return something like:

> I/TEST: onAdLoaded: com.mobfox.adapter.MobFoxAdapter

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Xamarin.iOS so the following is in C#, but maybe it'll help you.  I've used this code to determine whether the ad is from iAd or from AdMob.  I wrote this quickly just for debugging purposes and this method will only tell you if the ad is from AdMob or something else, which in my case was always iAd.

```
var property = view.MediatedAdView.GetType().GetProperty("AdUnitID");

string adType;
if (property != null && property.GetValue(view.MediatedAdView) != null)
{
    adType = "AdMob";
}
else
{
    adType = "iAd";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ad.adNetworkClassName`. 
Example values I'm getting `GADMAdapterGoogleAdMobAds`, `GADMAdapterUnity`.

Works for both interstitial and rewarded video ads.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the actual class being used in the delegate. The code in Swift:

```
func interstitialDidReceiveAd(_ interstitial: GADInterstitial) {
  print("Interstitial adapter class name: \(interstitial.responseInfo.adNetworkClassName)")
}
```